# QGIS converting MultiPolygon to MultiSurface - can I disable QGIS from doing this?

Tags: qgis, geometry, multi-polygon, surface, true-curves

I have MultiPolygon data stored in a PostgreSQL DB (13.9) and am editing this through QGIS (using 3.28.3-Firenze). Occasionally when editing, some features are saved back as MultiSurface features. This doesn't affect them in QGIS and is hard to notice but it is causing issues elsewhere when reading the geometries.

Is there a way to stop QGIS from changing the geometry type? Or from creating curves (if that's the cause)?

I'm not sure what tool is causing the issue, perhaps Advanced editing - move or scale. The CRS of the dataset is WGS84.